# Spring dataRest insertion how to pass only id relationship instead entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-rest

I have 2 Entities with a OneToOne relationShip, this way:

Grupo.java:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "administradorId")
private Usuario administrador;
```

Usuario.java:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "administrador",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
private Grupo grupo;
```

When insert a group via Post Request I'm want to do it this way:

```
{
"titulo":"title",
"descripcion":"cosa",
"activo":true,
"administrador":2,
"portada": ""
}
```

But the only way it works is,

```
 {
    "titulo":"title",
    "descripcion":"cosa",
    "activo":true,
    "administrador": {"id":2},
    "portada": ""
    }
```

I Dont want to pass the entire Entity {"id":2} only want to pass 2.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom serializer:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User> {
      public void serialize(User value, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeNumber(user.getId());
     }
 }
```

And need to add an annotation called @JsonDeserialize.

```
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
  ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "administradorId")
  @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer. Class) 
   private Usuario administrador;
```

Comment: I found that the thing i need is a CustomDeserializer but you post a Serializer, can you help me to construct the first one.

Comment: Of course, I didn't read well your question xD sorry I'm answering you from my phone xD